# '&' becomes '&amp;' when trying to get contents from a URL

Tags: php, html, apache, nginx

I was running my WebServer for months with the same Algorithm where I got the content of a URL by using this line of code:

```
$response = file_get_contents('http://femoso.de:8019/api/2/getVendorLogin?' . http_build_query(array('vendor'=>$vendor,'user'=>$login,'pw'=>$pw),'','&'));
```

But now something must have changed as out of sudden it stopped working.

In earlier days the URL looked like it should have been:

```
http://femoso.de:8019/api/2/getVendorLogin?vendor=100&user=test&pw=test
```

but now I get an error in my nginx log saying that I requested the following URL which returned a 403

```
http://femoso.de:8019/api/2/getVendorLogin?vendor=100&amp;user=test&amp;pw=test
```

I know that something changed on the target server, but I think that shouldn't affect me or not?!

I already spent hours and hours of reading and searching through Google and Stackoverflow, but all the suggested ways as

urlencode() or
htmlspecialchars() etc...

didn't work for me.

For your information, the environment is a zend application with a nginx server on my end and a php webservice with apache on the other end.

Like I said, it changed without any change on my side!

Thanks

Comment: Interesting. Has changing the arg_separator (third parameter of `http_build_query`) any effect on the generated url?

Comment: If I change the arg_seperator to '&amp;' for example, I get the URL with &amp;amp;user etc. ...

Comment: that indicates some post processing is happening somewhere. maybe there is a tidy output buffer changing the urls. Out of curiosity, does the generated HTML show the entities or does only nginx tell you so?

Comment: I got the same feeling about the post processing, but as I haven't changed anything around there, I thought this is maybe a problem with the remote server?! nginx tells me that I requested this faulty url and says that it returned a 403 which causes a php error

Comment: @Evils, What PHP version is your server currently running? The `arg_separator` parameter has been added in 5.1.2. A (accidental) downgrade is not very likely though..

Comment: Could the server be returning a redirect to that URL?

Comment: What do you see if you do `$url = 'http://femoso.de:8019/api/2/getVendorLogin?' . http_build_query(array('vendor'=>$vendor,'user'=>$login,'pw'=>$pw),'','&'); echo $url;` ?

Comment: @netiul It's PHP 5.4.9

Comment: @Barmer I can't tell as I have no control over the remote server. Requesting this URL with the right '&' gives me the correct result without any rewrite or obvious redirect

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's find out the culprit!

1) Is it `http_build_query` ? Try replacing:

```
'http://femoso.de:8019/api/2/getVendorLogin?' . http_build_query(array('vendor'=>$vendor,'user'=>$login,'pw'=>$pw)
```

with:

```
"http://femoso.de:8019/api/2/getVendorLogin?vendor={$vendor}&user={$login}&pw={$pw}"
```

2) Is some kind of post-processing in the place? Try replacing `'&'` with `chr(38)`

3) Maybe give a try and [play](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.curl-setopt.php) a little bit with cURL?

```
$ch = curl_init();

curl_setopt_array($ch, array(
    CURLOPT_URL => 'http://femoso.de:8019/api/2/getVendorLogin?' . http_build_query(array('vendor'=>$vendor,'user'=>$login,'pw'=>$pw),
    CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => true,
    CURLOPT_HEADER => true, // include response header in result
    //CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION => true, // uncomment to follow redirects
    CURLINFO_HEADER_OUT => true, // track request header, see var_dump below
));

$data = curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);

var_dump($data, curl_getinfo($ch, CURLINFO_HEADER_OUT));
exit;
```

Comment: It's totally weird... The first options brings the same output as before &amp; instead of &    The second option brings a chr(38) instead of a $ ... strange world

Comment: By any chance, didn't you left the quotes around chr(38)?

Comment: This is what I tried now    $response = file_get_contents('http://femoso.de:8019/api/2/getVendorLogin?vendor=' . $vendor . "chr(38)" . 'user=' . $login . "chr(38)" . 'pw=' . $pw );

Comment: If I do it without any quotes as in    $response = file_get_contents('http://femoso.de:8019/api/2/getVendorLogin?vendor=' . $vendor . chr(38) . 'user=' . $login . chr(38) . 'pw=' . $pw );
I'll get a &amp; again instead of the &

Comment: Assuming you didn't do a mistake, looks like the problem isn't in the PHP, so either your server or the remote application somehow broke. I added a fun playground with cURL in my answer.

Comment: Hi, thanks for all your kind support. It seems to be a problem with UTF-8 in one of my other files... I went back to an old git commit and found my problem ...

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like your `arg_separator.output` is set to `"&amp;"` in your php.ini.  Either comment that line out or change to just `"&"`

Answer (score 0):

I'm no expert but that's the way the computer reads the address since it's a special character. Something with encoding. Simple fix would be to to filter by utilizing str_replace(). Something along those lines.

Comment: Tried that, had no effect at all